# DB Input Talend Job Execution

Tags: talend

I am new to Talend, I am had created a Job in Talend as below

[image]

I am getting the Result set from DBInput 1, DBInput 2 and DBInput3 and comparing the three Resultset using `tMap` and Updating a table using the DBOutput

The sequence should be like this First DBInput 1 resultset is got and then DBInput 2 resultset is got
and then DBInput 2 resultset is got and compare the three resultsets

But the DBInput 2 executes first and the result set is got and comarision is done before the DBInput 1 and DBInput 3 executes, So I am not able to update the table because of this

My tMap Sequence is
[image]

Can anyone please point me what is wrong in this sequence,

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the order of lookups from inside the tMap. On the input side (left side), select the lookup table, it will be highlighted in yellow, then using the arrows in the upper left corner move them up or down.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the response I had added my tMap sequence Please see that too

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "comparing the three Resultset" ? what is the condition to update your target table ?

Comment: Thank you very much for the infomation, I had changed the rows as said by you and it is working :)